# 10.12 Doesn't display the value expected

Tags: floating-point, precision

These are the c statements. why 10.12 doesn't display the value expected?

> int main(){
>
> ```
>     printf("10.10 =%.15lf\n",1.10);
>     printf("10.12 = %.15lf\n",10.12);
>     printf("10.15 = %.15lf\n",10.15);
>     return 0; }
> ```

Expected Output:-

10.10 =10.100000000000000

10.12 = 10.120000000000000

10.15 = 10.150000000000000

Actual Output:-

10.10 =10.100000000000000

10.12 = 10.119999999999999

10.15 = 10.150000000000000

Answer (score 3):

Typical [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can exactly represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.  10.12 is **not** one of them as each encodable value is some 53 bit integer times some power of 2 and <sup>1012</sup>/<sub>100</sub> is not exactly representable as such.  Instead a nearby value is encoded:  5697053528623677 * 2<sup>-49</sup>.

```
10.119999999999999218...
```

When printed with sufficient decimal precession, its rounded difference from 10.12 appears.

---

It is the same for 10.10 and 10.15 if more precision if used.

```
// 123456789012345 
10.099999999999999644...
10.119999999999999218...
10.150000000000000355...
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason is this pipeline:

1. The string `10.12`, a decimal number
2. is parsed and transformed into a *binary* IEEE 754 floating point as well as possible.

   - [This page](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) is relevant, although it uses 32-bit (single precision) floating points. See attached image. (Note that the page itself displays the stored float in decimal notation, which is the next step)
3. The binary IEEE 754 floating point representation is then printed out in decimal format as well as possible. There are some interesting articles on printing out floating points in decimal format. For example:

   - [Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.52.2247), Robert Burger and R. Kent Dybvig, *ACM SIGPLAN 96*
   - [How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/gcl-devel/2012-10/pdfkieTlklRzN.pdf), Guy L. Steele and Jon White, *ACM SIGPLAN 9O*

[image: a floating point representation]